# How do I dynamically create ListBox items from code in C# (Winrt)

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-runtime

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here,

I am faced with the task of creating a screen that I must construct using a message sent to me from over a socket.  The screen can consist of your standard GUI items, and this includes a list/table.
I can see plenty of code and tips on how to create a table using a DataTemplate in XAML, however I have 2 (related) things which I am struggling with.

1. What is the best way to create a list from code (WinRT/c#), that may contain a complicated component heirachy (buttons/images inside a panel laid out by me).  I see that the ItemContainerGenerator is a sealed class so I can't roll my own...  Do I create my own DataTemplate via code some how?
2. How do I implement row recycling?  Will I need to add bindings for every little parameter like border colour and alignment, and if so would this have a significant impact on performance??

Any pointers will definitely be appreciated.  (I'm more at home in Android/Java and c# is an exciting new world for me)

Cheers,

Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinRT does not really have support for representation of hierarchical data on a single screen. If you look at how file picker is implemented - you need to dig into subfolders one by one and then go back the same way.

If your hierarchy is complicated, but relatively flat - using DataTemplates might be enough, though for Metro apps - you do not really want your hierarchy to be complicated and you might want to try to think how to make it easier to be easily consumed in the touch centric UI.

What do you mean by row recycling? A ListView or ListBox uses a VirtualizingStackPanel as its ItemsPanel by default and virtualizes rows or columns automatically. If you want anything more custom - you might need to implement your own ItemsControl subclass instead.

Comment: Thanks Filip, The underlying components will generally be relatively flat - the heirachy will come from 'shaded areas' which contain other components.
As this is a toolkit to display screens constructed elsewhere, I'm really at the mercy of whoever designed the screen as far as good UI design goes.  I have to display it how it's been designed regardless.  :(

Comment: My understanding of VirtualizingStackPanel is that it assists with creating and removing panels as they become needed - but does it reuse components that have been removed when it creates them?  I couldn't see anywhere that it specified that this took place.  In any case, how do I tell it what to create or how to recycle it???

Comment: I don't think you can - it actually only reuses the layout generated from the actual DataTemplate, so for anything more custom - if you want to recycle the layouts you generated from your metadata - you will need to roll your own controls and logic.